# Webcam access from JavaFx

Tags: javafx, jmf

Does the latest JavaFx version support streaming webcam video? Is it possible to get it through JMF in fx?

Comment: I don't know enough to post an answer, but I'd be surprised if this wasn't doable, so don't give up ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem you can do it yet, see e.g. [this recent post](http://www.ksptechinc.com/blogs/28-javafx/64-webcam).

However, there seems to be several examples of using JMF to be able to at least capture an image.  You might also try JNA.

Comment: knock knock, wakeup its 2011 almost, javaFX is in charge for those.

Comment: @Stackfan No need for smugness; "answered Oct 7 '09 at 14:48", as you probably can read.  So if things have changed, hurray!

Comment: Sorry, not yet hurray as you need to follow a hard way to get this working. JavaFx you can still bring other video/audio libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Almost 7 years later from when the question was asked and there still isn't 'native' JavaFX support for displaying a stream from a webcam (as far as I am aware).

However I managed to achieve it using the [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) library and displaying into an `ImageView`. It's probably inefficient but OpenCV gives you the possibilities of processing the 'stream' too. Although all one might want to do is just display the stream, not modify it.

Comment: yep, I asked it 7 years ago when we wanted to have a hybrid app where we wanted to have the rich GUI  capabilities of FX combined with the speed and reliability of our code mostly done in C++ (such as opencv). This was before iPad was born and Android was much in it's infancy.  Now there are efforts (https://developer.nvidia.com/codeworks-android) but nothing equivalent and as vertically integrated as iOS or Android where you can say it's robotech meets UX fluidly.