# How to capture webcam input in java without an external library?

Tags: java

My question is exactly as the title states. I've spent some time googling and all I can find are recommendations to use external libraries. However, I'd like to do this without using any external libraries and documentation is lacking on how to go about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid it is not possible. The two main approaches in java is to use either JMF or openCV. JavaFX has no plan to develop a Webcam API so it is not going to change soon.

You should look at this question: [How can I take image at webcam with javaFX at win7 64bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552167/how-can-i-take-image-at-webcam-with-javafx-at-win7-64bit)

Here is a link to javafx + opencv integration: http://ladstatt.blogspot.fr/2013/04/using-isight-camera-with-javafx.html

JavaFX + JMF does not seem to work now: [Webcam access from JavaFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495345/webcam-access-from-javafx)

But there is hope with JavaFX 8: https://github.com/carldea/WebcamFX

Answer (score 0):

Not possible without external libs unless you depend on JNI. Period.

In the past I got good results using JTwain-based solutions.